# Getting the transformation matrix of an animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, matrix, transformation

I would like to obtain the transformation matrix of an animation to calculate the position of the view that was animated.

It seems the Animation class has a method called getTransformation that can be used to obtain the transformation applied to the view.

However, if I use getTransformation before starting the animation I obtain the identity matrix. And if I use it like this:

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    Transformation t = new Transformation();
    animation.getTransformation(animation.getDuration(), t);
}
```

The program enters an infite loop because getTransformation seems to trigger onAnimationEnd (why?).

How should I use getTransformation to obtain the transformation matrix of an animation? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Because, for some reason, that is the way getTransformation is coded.

http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.5/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/animation/Animation.java

It looks like you can check hasEnded() to see if the animation is complete. Try something like this:

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
   if ( animation.hasEnded() )
       return;

   Transformation t= new Transformation();
   animation.getTransformation(animation.getDuration(), t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem too when I want to getTransformation() for next animation after previous animation done, then infinite loop cause stackoverflow.

I analyzed problem with source code of Android from [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.2_r1/android/view/animation/Animation.java#Animation.getTransformation%28long%2Candroid.view.animation.Transformation%29), with codes below in `getTransformation()`, I never find any problem which would cause infinite loop, as only place call  `onAnimationEnd()`, it will set `mEnded` to true. Next time call `getTransformation()`, it should be blocked by `if(!mEnded)`, but it's not.

```
    if (expired) {
        if (mRepeatCount == mRepeated) {
            if (!mEnded) {
                mEnded = true;   //this is not real!!!
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onAnimationEnd(this);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (mRepeatCount > 0) {
                mRepeated++;
            }

            if (mRepeatMode == REVERSE) {
                mCycleFlip = !mCycleFlip;
            }

            mStartTime = -1;
            mMore = true;

            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onAnimationRepeat(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

It seams grepcode is not correct with this segments of code. The truth is that `eEnded = true` is set after `onAnimationEnd()` called:

```
    if (!mEnded) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onAnimationEnd(this);
            }
            //it happen after onAnimationEnd(). cancel() is also does as this
            mEnded = true; 
        }
```

That should explain why infinite loop happen. Even you check `animation.hasEnded()` would not help, as it could not reach to set mEnded to true.

The ways I hack with this problem are:
Set flag in listener to guard:

```
boolean needBlock = false;
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
   if ( needBlock ) return;

   needBlock = true;
   Transformation t= new Transformation();
   animation.getTransformation(animation.getDuration(), t);
}
```

Clear AnimationListner. If required, we can set back after

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
   animation.setAnimationListener(null);
   Transformation t= new Transformation();
   animation.getTransformation(animation.getDuration(), t);
   animation.setAnimationListener(this);
}
```

Comment: The android code from GrepCode is version2.2.2 For android version <= 2.1 `mEnded = true` is really behind `onAnimationEnd()`. I developed android on level 8, so that issue happen. For latest version of android, it should not has such infinite loop